# Parsing from:x; but not lfrom:x;

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I am trying to parse a string with something like :

```
preg_match( "|from:(.*?);|", $string, $match);
```

But then I found that the string can also contain `lfrom:` and `_from:`

A few examples of how the string can be:

> var1:34234;from:website1.com;lfrom:website2.com;var2:343423;
>   lfrom:website1.com;var1:4234234;from:website2.com
>   from:website1.com;_from:website2.com;lfrom:website2.com;var1:43523;

How can I parse only `from:(.*?);` and not `lfrom`, `_from`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was gonna give you the solution but I better explain you about the lookbehind modifier.

In regex each time you "match" a `h` for example, that `h` will add 1 to the pointer of where the regex is at the moment so you dont want to "add" nothing to the pointer. You just want to look if the `from` is preceded by a `;\s\b` or the start of the string. You don't want to match the VOID because there are voids everywhere!!

So, an example: `(?<a)b` that would match a `b` that has an `a` before it. So it just does the next: When a `b` found it looks before it, if there is an `a` it matches the regex.

So... `(?<=[;\s\b]|^)from:(\w+\.\w+)` Would match a `from` that right before it has `[;\s\b] OR ^ (The string start)`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mQ0zR4)

Pretty easy, huh!?

Answer (score 1):

You could either use an assertion:

```
|(?<!l)from:(.*?);|
```

Or look for the preceding `;` or line start:

```
|(;|^)from:(.*?);|m
```

It might also be a good idea to replace the generic `.*?` match with `[^;]*`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming preceding `from` is whitespace or a `;`

```
/[\s\b;]from:([^;]+);/
```

This will only match `from` preceeded by a space, word boundary, or `;`. I also prefer to narrow captures, i.e. `[^;]+` vs. `[.*?]`;.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called (negative) lookbehind, which asserts that your current position is (not) preceded by certain things. I guess, in this case I would go with a positive lookbehind, and assert that `from` is preceded by a the start of the string, a line-break or a `;`:

```
preg_match('|(?<=^|;)from:(.*?);|m', $string, $match);
```

Make sure to you multi-line mode `m`, so that `^` will also match at the start of each line and not just at the start of the string.

If you **only** wanted to exlude `l` and `_` in front of `from` but accept any other characters, then a negative lookbehind might be what you are looking for:

```
preg_match('|(?<![l_])from:(.*?);|m', $string, $match);
```

The convenient thing about lookbehinds is, that they are not included in the actual match. They just check what's there without actually consuming it. [Here is some reading.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)